# The uniqueness of positive integer linear combination of prime factors.

Tags: linear-algebra, prime-numbers, linear-programming

I was solving something and came up with an unusual solution that worked no matter what example I explored. Now I want to know whether there is such regularity.
So we have the linear combination $ c_1 \cdot p_1^1 + c_2 \cdot p_2^2+ ...+ c_n \cdot p_n^n = k$ where $c_i $-s are  Positive Integers and $p_i$ is the i-th prime number.
We also have the sum of all the $c_i$-s (for example $c_1 + c_2 + ... + c_n = b$).
I want to know whether there is a unique set of $c_i$-s if k and b are fixed numbers :

P.s. I used Z3 solver and it always "guessed" the $c_i$-s.

Comment: There are fixed ways to brute force a k value.

Comment: Eg. k and b opposite parity leads to $c_1$ being odd.

Comment: Ok, but that doesn't give me much information.
I am wondering if my assumption that given some k and some b, we can certainly say that the found $c_i$-s are unique is true.
Or is there a counterexample, so that I know that my assumption is false ?

Comment: Do you understand why k and b opposite parity leads to $c_1$ being odd ? Maybe you can generalize the parity conditions.

Comment: what if  they arent opposite parity? my problem is determining if the $c_i$-s that I found  are for sure unique or not .

Or even if they are what if there are 2 sets of coefficients where first ones are odd like u mention .

Comment: I know for certain that there is such linear combination that is equal to k and the sum is equal to b . I just need to know whether its unique or not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150226/discussion-between-roddy-macphee-and-h-h).

Comment: This is equivalent to determine if there exist $c_i$ (positive or not) such $c_1 \cdot p_1^1 + c_2 \cdot p_2^2+ ...+ c_n \cdot p_n^n = 0$